# Opencart - multistore admin login redirection to default store after login

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart

I'm using opencart version `1.5.5.1` for our website. The site uses opencart multi-store feature also. The multi-store features are working fine.

Consider 2 stores - storedefault.com and storeone.com. A vendor creates an account at storeone.com. When he tries to login by calling `storeone.com/admin`, the signing form is displayed but after login the url gets redirected to `storedefault.com/admin`.

Is it possible to stay at `storeone.com/admin` after login?

Please help.

Comment: I guess it is possible but cannot tell You how nor why this happens. I would suppose that using multistore both the frontend and backend are using their defined URLs, but I have never worked with multistore thus cannot help You, sorry.

Comment: I think this happens as storedefault.com is the main root store and gives the vendor access to all other stores.

Comment: Vendor can access his products only. The multi-store features are working fine. The problem is that after login the url gets redirected to storedefault.com/admin.

Comment: I have been working on that also changing manually the sql dabase table sore, nothing; what worked for me? a new fresh install with european language packs, don't ask me why, no idea, hope it helps. good luck

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is the expected behaviour of open-cart since it uses one administration for multiple stores.

If you want a separate admin per store, you should use one or another extension. For example: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8353&filter_search=multi-admin

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't need to limit the products based on store as I've already implemented multi vendors. So vendors can see only their products. The only problem is the url redirection to default store.

Comment: Before buy this extension please see the all comment.I think this extension is a fake. @TOM Lankhorst

Answer (score 0):

Opencart uses a central admin system by design.

If you are trying to have the admin appear differently depending on the person signing in then this is possible without using different addresses. You can make some changes to the controller and model files to get this outcome.

If you are using a multivendor addon then make the changes within the vqmod as it is likely already making changes if a vendor signs in.